# Does Selenium v3.141 support Java 13?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, java-13

Confirmation on below issue :

Has Selenium 3.141 support for jdk 13?

Please refer me which combination of java or selenium versions I can use.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and [mcve]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  Why not try it and see?

Answer (score 4):

We are yet to see any official documentation released if the latest version of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) supports [java-13](/questions/tagged/java-13).

However there are some existing compatibility issues between **Selenium** and [java](/questions/tagged/java) versions other than [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) as follows:

- [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9): [An illegal reflective access operation has occurred while executing automated tests using Selenium and Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58100247/an-illegal-reflective-access-operation-has-occurred-while-executing-automated-te/58132830#58132830)
- [java-11](/questions/tagged/java-11): [Unable to import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver using Selenium and Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876955/unable-to-import-org-openqa-selenium-webdriver-using-selenium-and-java-11/54880228#54880228)

---

### Solution

The strategic solution will be to install the latest version of [JDK 8u341](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and execute the *@Tests*