# "java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.apache.bsf.BSFManager not in module" error with ChromeDriver Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, java-module, java-13

I am using eclipse 09-2019 with jdk13 and selenium 3.0.1 .jar file.

My Code is:

```
package package1;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Script1
{
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
          System.out.println("Hii");
          System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
          driver.get("http://www.google.com");
      }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.apache.bsf.BSFManager not in module
```

Comment: This is not valid code, please fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 11 Unable to derive module descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54682417/java-11-unable-to-derive-module-descriptor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### InvalidModuleDescriptorException

[InvalidModuleDescriptorException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/module/InvalidModuleDescriptorException.html) is thrown when reading a module descriptor and the module descriptor is found to be malformed or otherwise cannot be interpreted as a module descriptor.

*InvalidModuleDescriptorException* can be raised in either of the following scenarios:

1. Issues with the Java project.
2. Issues with the Java package with in a Java project.
3. Issues with the Java class with in a Java package.

However, as per the discussion in [Does Selenium v3.141 support Java 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531018/does-selenium-v3-141-support-java-13/58538235#58538235) it seems the latest version of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) still doesn't supports [java-13](/questions/tagged/java-13).

---

### Solution

The strategic solution will be to install the latest version of [**JDK 8u222**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and execute the *@Tests*

Additionally, you also need to replace uppercap **W** with the lowercap **w** in the `System.setProperty()` line. So, effectively, you need to replace:

```
System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
```

With

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
```

---

### Additional Consideration

Additionally, ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))

Comment: I switched to JDK 8 and it worked fine after that. Thanks @DebanjanB