# org.openqa.selenium.webdriver is not accessible error using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser, java-13

I installed latest java 13.0 and latest Selenium version, got error  "org.openqa.selenium.webdriver is not accessible" so changed the compliance level to 1.8 from 13.

I'm getting the error shown in the picture:

[image: Im getting the error shown in the picture]

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.webdriver is not accessible
```

...implies that the *org.openqa.selenium.webdriver* was not accessible by your program.

---

As per the snapshot you shared, you shouldn't keep the class name with in the program as **Java** as it is a reserved word.

### Solution

You need to take either of the following steps:

- Either change the name of the *class* from **Java** to something else, e.g. **`testJava`**
- Or you may have to delete this program all together and create a new class, e.g. **`testJava`**

---

### tl; dr

[Does Selenium v3.141 support Java 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531018/does-selenium-v3-141-support-java-13/58538235#58538235)

Comment: *Java as it is a key word*!! ... did you try the code by yourself?

Comment: Few points to what I could notice from the answer. There is no reason stated behind the solutions suggested. The TLDR eventually points to an eligible duplicate and the question if not clear can be asked in comments.

Comment: @Naman Agreed, but still **Java** being a keyword would have left unaddressed.