# Selenium throwing TimeoutException with Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' then loading correctly the page with Burp

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, burp

I am using Selenium in a Burp plugin and I am using the latest version of Browsers and WebDrivers. The page I am trying to load has no issue if the Proxy is not set, but it freezes when I set it to be listened by Burp on localhost:8080. The issue is faced both in Chrome and in Firefox, so it can't be a Certificate problem since Chrome gets Certificate Authorities from the System, where the CA_cert is successfully installed.
Burp is listening, as usual, on 127.0.0.1:8080, but if I run code like

```
try {
    webDriver.get("https://www.nytimes.com/");
} catch (InterruptException e) {
    print(e.getMessage(e.getClass().getCanonicalName() + "\nError message: " + e.getMessage()));
}
```

Shows the following error

```
Timeout loading page after 10000ms
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'MSI', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '13.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 76.0.1, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20200507114007, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.24.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 16328, moz:profile: C:\Users\Stefano\AppData\Lo..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10.0, proxy: Proxy(manual, http=127.0.0...., rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: c8b392fe-b8d7-4781-8268-7e34a9272a35
```

The awkward thing is that after the timeout, set as 10 seconds, the page is loaded correctly and the browser stop here.

EDIT

After downgrading Burp to 2020.2.1 and Java 8, I am still getting those errors.
In Firefox

```
Timeout loading page after 10000ms
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'MSI', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '12.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 76.0.1, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20200507114007, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.24.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 8652, moz:profile: C:\Users\Stefano\AppData\Lo..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10.0, proxy: Proxy(manual, http=127.0.0...., rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: ea6a8588-cc2c-426b-994c-28ccccfd0ac1
```

While in Chrome

```
timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.001
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'MSI', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '12.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 81.0.4044.138, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 81.0.4044.138 (8c6c7ba89cc9..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Stefano\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:51033}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(manual, http=127.0.0...., setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 8bd64565ca51e4e96cd8ab2825e85447
```

Stacktrace with Firefox and Geckodriver 0.24

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timeout loading page after 10000ms
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'MSI', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '12.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 76.0.1, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20200507114007, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.24.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 11348, moz:profile: C:\Users\Stefano\AppData\Lo..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10.0, proxy: Proxy(manual, http=127.0.0...., rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: c83e1ba2-eb5c-4a70-850f-4f6bcafd76e6
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:277)
    at burp.BurpExtender.runBrowserAutomatization(BurpExtender.java:266)
    at burp.SAMLChecks_GUI.runAutomatizationButtonActionPerformed(SAMLChecks_GUI.java:438)
    at burp.SAMLChecks_GUI.access$300(SAMLChecks_GUI.java:36)
    at burp.SAMLChecks_GUI$4.actionPerformed(SAMLChecks_GUI.java:139)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Stacktrace with Chrome and its driver

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.000
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'MSI', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '12.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 81.0.4044.138, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 81.0.4044.138 (8c6c7ba89cc9..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Stefano\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:51672}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(manual, http=127.0.0...., setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 3576cf9353d41d42077d8b2e5063226f
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:277)
    at burp.BurpExtender.runBrowserAutomatization(BurpExtender.java:266)
    at burp.SAMLChecks_GUI.runAutomatizationButtonActionPerformed(SAMLChecks_GUI.java:438)
    at burp.SAMLChecks_GUI.access$300(SAMLChecks_GUI.java:36)
    at burp.SAMLChecks_GUI$4.actionPerformed(SAMLChecks_GUI.java:139)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Timeout loading page after 10000ms
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'MSI', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '13.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 76.0.1, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20200507114007, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.24.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 16328, moz:profile: C:\Users\Stefano\AppData\Lo..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10.0, proxy: Proxy(manual, http=127.0.0...., rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: c8b392fe-b8d7-4781-8268-7e34a9272a35
```

...implies that the *GeckoDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Firefox Browser* session.

---

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **unknown**, i.e. *unrecognized*.
- Your *JDK version* is **13.0.2** which is not supported.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Does Selenium v3.141 support Java 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531018/does-selenium-v3-141-support-java-13/58538235#58538235)

- Your *GeckoDriver* version is unknown to us.
- Your *Firefox* version is **76.0.1**.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v13.0.2* , *Selenium Client* , *GeckoDriver* and the *Firefox Browser v76.0.1*.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to current levels [JDK 8u251](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *GeckoDriver* is upgraded to [GeckoDriver v0.26.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0) level.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Hi, the Selenium version I am using is 3.141.59, and I am including in through Maven. Also, the Java version I have installed on my PC is 11.0.7, which is displayed both using the java -version command and javac -version. GeckoDriver is 0.24 version because the 0.25 and 0.26 suffers of a bug described here https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases involving Visual Studio redistributable However, the 0.24 should be compatible with Firefox 76.0.1. Also, Burp 2020.4 does not longer support Java 8. So, which Java version should I install?

Comment: @Stefano To garner optimum test results with Selenium you need to downgrade to JDK 8.

Comment: I downgraded Burp to support Java 8 and installed JDK 8u251, I updated the answer because I am still getting the error.

Comment: @Stefano Can you update the question with the recent error stacktrace please?