# NoSuchElementExeption in Docker but working fine in localhost

Tags: java, docker, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

i have programmed a test automation in selenium, which also works when i run it in eclipse. I want to run it in Docker but there I always face the Expetion NoSuchElement. I really hope someone can help me. So here is what I did:

```
final static String websiteUnderTest = "https://test.com";

final static String remoteWebDriverUrl = "http://selenium:4444/wd/hub";

//       Docker Browser setting
        Capabilities chromeCapabilities = new ChromeOptions();
        ((ChromeOptions) chromeCapabilities).addArguments("--headless");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteWebDriverUrl), chromeCapabilities);

    driver.get(websiteUnderTest);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        login();
```

The login:

```
public static void login() throws InterruptedException {
        // ---Login LogTicks---
        jse6 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        System.out.println("Login User");
        
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("userid")));
    
        WebElement userID = driver.findElement(By.id("userid"));
        jse6.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"+userID.getLocation().y+")");
        userID.click();
        userID.sendKeys("PID6D1F");
        driver.findElement(By.id("next-btn")).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("password")));
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
        password.sendKeys("LogTicksPool-ID");
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginSubmitButton")).click();

        System.out.println("User PID6D1F has login");
    }
```

I always get that:

```
tests_1     | Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: userid (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
tests_1     |   at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:113)
tests_1     |   at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:283)
tests_1     |   at SeleniumTests.login(SeleniumTests.java:99)
tests_1     |   at SeleniumTests.main(SeleniumTests.java:49)
tests_1     | Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.id: userid
tests_1     | For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
tests_1     | Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
tests_1     | System info: host: '390560c4caf4', ip: '172.18.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.19.76-linuxkit', java.version: '10.0.2'
tests_1     | Driver info: driver.version: unknown
tests_1     |   at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.lambda$findElement$0(ExpectedConditions.java:896)
tests_1     |   at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:397)
tests_1     |   at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:895)
tests_1     |   at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:44)
tests_1     |   at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:206)
tests_1     |   at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:202)
tests_1     |   at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:260)
tests_1     |   ... 2 more
```

And as you can see in the exeption I already have a waiter.

I am greatfull for every help!
Thank you

Comment: I have no exp with docker or selenium, but does't this local path `"C:\\Users\\calisay\\eclipse-workspace\\LogTicks-Testautomatisierung\\driver\\chromedriver.exe"` makes it only run in your machine?

Comment: Yes I only use that path when I run it local in Eclipse. The second part of my Code with the comment "Docker Browser setting" is what I use when i want to run it in Docker.

Comment: Having the exact same issue - everything works in localhost but not in Docker - did you ever figure out why? @sunxca

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
tests_1     | Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
tests_1     | System info: host: '390560c4caf4', ip: '172.18.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.19.76-linuxkit', java.version: '10.0.2'
tests_1     | Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to communicate with the *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

As per the error trace logs, you are using `java.version: '10.0.2'` which is still not fully supported. You can find a relevant discussion in [Does Selenium v3.141 support Java 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531018/does-selenium-v3-141-support-java-13/58538235#58538235)

However,

```
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
```

implies [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091121/why-doesnt-chromedriver-require-chrome-or-chromium/51096327#51096327) is unable to recognise [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) client version. Moreover,

```
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

implies *ChromeDriver* isn't recognized back.

So there is a clear mismatch between *Selenium Client* , *ChromeDriver* and the *Chrome Browser*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u251](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v83.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 83.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v83.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: I did everything as you said but it's still not working... Same Issue :(