# The eclipse IDE doesn't import its WebDriver interface, as i have configured the BuildPath adding its required JAR & driver files?

Tags: eclipse, selenium, webdriver, buildpath, java-14

Whenever I write a `WebDriver`, it doesn't import the packages as defined. Instead, it ask to create an interface called WebDriver. I'm using the JDK 14 and Eclipse 4.16.0.

```
package package1;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems required JAR didn't add successfully.  Try to download valid jar file and then import as mentioned [here](https://www.edureka.co/community/4028/how-to-import-a-jar-file-in-eclipse) or https://stackoverflow.com/a/3280451/5097027

Answer (score -1):

We are yet to see any official documentation released if the latest version of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) supports [java-14](/questions/tagged/java-14).

However there are some existing compatibility issues between **Selenium** and [java](/questions/tagged/java) versions other than [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) as follows:

- [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9): [An illegal reflective access operation has occurred while executing automated tests using Selenium and Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58100247/an-illegal-reflective-access-operation-has-occurred-while-executing-automated-te/58132830#58132830)
- [java-11](/questions/tagged/java-11): [Unable to import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver using Selenium and Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876955/unable-to-import-org-openqa-selenium-webdriver-using-selenium-and-java-11/54880228#54880228)
- [java-13](/questions/tagged/java-13): [Does Selenium v3.141 support Java 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531018/does-selenium-v3-141-support-java-13/58538235#58538235)

---

### Solution

The strategic solution will be to install the latest version of [JDK 8u352](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and execute the *@Tests*

Comment: meaning that the selenium doesn't support the newer version of JAVA ??

Comment: @SaaSh Yes, that's it.

Comment: So which JDK ver should I go for ?
and the other issue I found is whenever I try to instantiate the System.SetPropety; the SetProperty doesn't show at all after System. (control+space) ??

Comment: @SaaSh Please check the _Solution_ part.